# Is it possible to create Angular "Injector graph" similar to dependency graph of `dependency-cruiser`?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

So we're having a huge mess in our services at the project I'm working on and I wonder if there's any tool like [dependency-cruiser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-cruiser) but for Angular hierarchical injectors, to help visualize the state of things.

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/compodoc/ngd

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.